# How to access a pointer in a function with llvm api for c++

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, llvm, clang++

I want to write a dedicated language for some purpose. Basically it will be a bunch of functions that I will call from C code. Meaning I will pass a C pointer to struct to them. I want to experiment to check that I know how to manipulate those pointers with llvm. I wrote a little program that should take an integer of the struct and add 2 to it. I know the llvm IR isn't correct yet but
I can keep getting a segmentation fault while looking up the function.

CODE:

- struct definition:

```cpp
struct test_struct {
    char *b;
    int *c_dummy;
    int c;
    double f ;
};
struct test_struct tt{0,0,1,0};
```

- initialization:

```cpp
InitializeNativeTarget();
InitializeNativeTargetAsmPrinter();
InitializeNativeTargetAsmParser();
TheJIT = ExitOnErr(KaleidoscopeJIT::Create());
TheContext = std::make_unique<LLVMContext>();
TheModule = std::make_unique<Module>("my cool jit", *TheContext);
TheModule->setDataLayout(TheJIT->getDataLayout());
Builder = std::make_unique<IRBuilder<>>(*TheContext);
TheFPM = std::make_unique<legacy::FunctionPassManager>(TheModule.get());
TheFPM->add(createCFGSimplificationPass());
TheFPM->doInitialization();
```

```cpp
// create the value 2 to add later.
Value *v_const = ConstantInt::get(*TheContext,APInt(32,2,true));
// The return type of the function:
`Type *r_type = Type::getVoidTy(*TheContext);`
// define the struct params in llvm
```

```cpp
   ArrayRef<Type *> params = {Type::getInt8PtrTy(*TheContext),Type::getInt32PtrTy(*TheContext),
    Type::getInt32Ty(*TheContext),Type::getDoubleTy(*TheContext)};
    StructType *st = StructType::create(*TheContext,"s");
    st->setBody(params);
  /* Define function.*/
    ArrayRef<Type *> params_func = ArrayRef<Type *>(st);
    FunctionType *ft = FunctionType::get(r_type,params_func,false);
    Function *F = Function::Create(ft,Function::ExternalLinkage,"test",*TheModule); // add a function to the module
```

- Get the function and register to module. Get the entry BB and do the addition:

```cpp
     Value *c;
    BasicBlock *bb = BasicBlock::Create(*TheContext,"entry",F);
    Builder->SetInsertPoint(bb);
    Value *mem= Builder->CreateAlloca(st,nullptr); // This should allocate the param to stack.
    Value *mem_int= Builder->CreateAlloca(Type::getInt32Ty(*TheContext),nullptr); 
    // create a stac allocation for st.
    for (auto arg = F->arg_begin();arg != F->arg_end();arg++)
    {
        // bring st from the argument.
        Builder->CreateStore(arg,mem); // store rhe struct pointer in the stack.
        auto tmp_ar = arg;
        c = Builder->CreateStructGEP(st,mem,2); // take the second element from the pointer.
    }
    /* Store the argument in the stack*/
    mem_int = Builder->CreateLoad(st,c);  
    // perform add
    Value *res = Builder->CreateAdd(mem_int,v_const,"add tmp"); 
    // close of.
    Builder->CreateStore(res, mem_int);
    Builder->CreateRetVoid();
    /// added a basic block and returned void.

    TheModule->dump();
    auto RT = TheJIT->getMainJITDylib().createResourceTracker();
    auto TSM = ThreadSafeModule(std::move(TheModule),std::move(TheContext));
    ExitOnErr(TheJIT->addModule(std::move(TSM),RT));


    F->print(errs());
    TheJIT->dumpEE();
    do_test();
```

Now I test it with this function:

```cpp
void do_test()
{
    auto fsym = ExitOnErr(TheJIT->lookup("test"));
    void (*add_func)(struct test_struct *) = (void (*)(struct test_struct *))(intptr_t)fsym.getAddress();
    printf("Before func: %d\n", tt.c);
    add_func(&tt); // this should change t.c
    printf("After func: %d\n", tt.c);

}
```

I was expecting it to run and print the correct value. I get a segmentation fault on the line:

`auto fsym = ExitOnErr(TheJIT->lookup("test"));`
I compiled with

```
g++ -g test_ptr.cpp  `llvm-config --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core orcjit native` -O0 -o test_ptr
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `arg_begin`, `arg_end` iterators which will give you pointers to the argument.

```
for (auto arg = func->arg_begin(); arg != func->arg_end(); ++arg) {
    errs() << "Argument: " << arg->getName() << ", type: " << *arg->getType() << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Tried it same issue..